# Solr Document relations

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, filesystems, nosql

I am trying to index a "versioned file system" using Solr where:

- each file is an object identified by 32 byte guid (oGuid) and
- every single version of file can be identified by another 32 byte guid (vGuid).

For instance, the document below is added for file *"/tmp/x"*

```
path: /tmp/x
oGuid: fdf2eec39a8a42ca8fddb17ad65017ba
vGuid: b2f1d0204a0743ff82b0056c82ed84e6 
mtime: 2016-07-14T21:35:21Z
size: 12580
```

Then if another version of the same file comes in, I will add the document:

```
path: /tmp/x
oGuid: fdf2eec39a8a42ca8fddb17ad65017ba 
vGuid: 83dc77c8ed90439bbf38ae42c07bea13 
mtime: 2016-07-15T20:30:11Z
size: 1780
```

At this point, when user searches/browses the filesystem at a particular point in time, I have to return *the latest matching version of files as in that point in time*.

For example if user looks for file */tmp/x at* latest point in time. I need to return its newest version having
**vGuid:83dc77c8ed90439bbf38ae42c07bea13**

I thought of two possible approaches:

1. I could use **result grouping** and **group.sort** to return only the newest version of file at that point in time,  however grouping wouldn't be very efficient as there could be millions of files.
2. I could index all the versions of files as one document using multiValued fields, however that would return wrong results by matching values from two different versions and moreover we cannot sort on multivalued fields.

Could you please suggest some more efficient and functional approach? 
Thanks

Comment: How about keeping the version history in a separate core/collection and the current state in the main core/collection?

Comment: That would help if searches are mostly on current state but in my case searches will be on previous states (point in time searches).

Answer (score 0):

If the use cases are "latest version" and "at specific date" - I would probably double-index latest two versions of the file every time it changes. The latest version with a marker field (latest) and the the previous version the second time to now **not** have that marker.

This may also be possible to achieve with a custom update request processor (fetch and update latest record for the same ID), though it will not be a trivial implementation.

Alternatively, I would just have two collections, one for latest and one for all when specific date is specified. Index into the first one with overriding previous versions and into the second without.

Comment: Even if I double index/ have two collections it will help speeding up only latest search but I still have to do a group by for Point in time searches which I think will be the most performed search.

Comment: Then, you may want to look at post-filters instead. But you would have to write a custom one.

Comment: Would BlockJoins be right thing to use here? http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html